# will LAST_INSERT_ID function ever fail?

Tags: mysql

I have a registration procedure on mysql database and it works like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tblusers` (`uname`, `upwd`, `umail`) VALUES (RU_UNAME, RU_UPWD, RU_UMAIL);
select LAST_INSERT_ID() into @newuserid;

-- then use the @newuserid to make some work on other tables.
```

now I was wondering will it ever get the wrong id specially that the database will have a lot of inserts in other tables, then it might get an id of another table that is inserted between inserting the user and getting the last inserted id?

is there a chance of failure?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. Different connections to the database maintain their own separate `LAST_INSERT_ID`. Therefore some other client inserting records into `tblusers` won't affect your `LAST_INSERT_ID`.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is worth a read. It spells things out in quite a lot of detail.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses lock system, which does not allow 2 processes (2 calls to the script) to modify the same row. So the table won't crash*, but it's possible that MySQL can't handle the number of request in reasonable time and the requests will wait. You should always optimize your queries to be as fast as possible.

So, last inserted id wont failed.